# Android UI testing for MVVM architecture with Dagger2, Espresso and Mockito

Tags: android, mockito, dagger-2, android-espresso, dagger

I'm trying to add UI tests for the first time to an app, and I was looking at using espresso.

The app uses Dagger2 for DI with `@Inject` annotations for classes that should be injectable, and `AndroidInjection`/`AndroidSupportInjection` in screens (Activity / Fragment).

```
class Application : android.app.Application(), HasActivityInjector, HasServiceInjector {
...
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        initDagger()
        Timber.d("Application initialized successfully!")
    }

    protected open fun initDagger() {
        Components.initialize(this)
    }
}

object Components : ComponentFactory {
    private lateinit var sComponent: AppComponent

    fun initialize(app: Application) {
         sAppComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .applicationModule(ApplicationModule(this))
            .build()
    }
    // overrides
}

interface ComponentFactory {
    fun app(): AppComponent
    fun authenticated(): AuthenticatedComponent
}
```

Next the `Component`s and `Module`s. The `AppActivitiesModule` and `AuthenticatedActivitiesModule` are classes with `@ContributesAndroidInjector` for screens.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class, AppActivitiesModule::class, AndroidInjectionModule::class, AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class])
interface AppComponent {

    fun authenticatedComponentBuilder(): AuthenticatedComponent.Builder

    fun inject(app: Application)

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        fun build(): AppComponent

        fun applicationModule(applicationModule: ApplicationModule): Builder
    }
}

@Module
open class AppModule(private val application: Application) {
// some @Provides
}
```

```
@AuthenticatedScope
@Subcomponent(modules = [AuthenticatedModule::class, AuthenticatedActivitiesModule::class])
interface AuthenticatedComponent {

    fun inject(application: Application)

    @Subcomponent.Builder
    interface Builder {
        fun userModule(module: UserModule): Builder

        fun build(): AuthenticatedComponent
    }
}


@Module
class AuthenticatedModule(private val userId: Long,
                          private val userRole: User.Role) {
// Some @Provides @AuthenticatedScope
}
```

And a typical use case would be:

```
@Singleton
class AppLevelService 
@Inject constructor(...) { ... }

@AuthenticatedScope
class AuthenticatedLevelServices 
@Inject constructor(...) { ... }

class ViewModel 
@Inject constructor(private val appService: AppLevelService,
                    private val authService: AuthenticatedLevelServices) { ... }

class MyActivity : BaseActivity {
    @Inject 
    lateinit var vmProvider: Provide<ViewModel>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this)
    }
}
```

How can I make the test setup for this "type" of dagger usage?

I find a lot of examples of testing with dagger2 but for `@Provides` annotations, and I'm thinking there should be a way to mock injectable classes with `@Inject`.

I've tried `DaggerMock` but I get:

> You must define overridden objects using a @Provides annotated method instead of using @Inject annotation

Not that it should affect anything, but I'm also using a custom Runner with `DexOpener`.

Any ideas or good documentation / examples for testing this setup?

Comment: I went through the same ordeal last week. This really helped me in mocking the `Component` http://blog.sqisland.com/2015/04/dagger-2-espresso-2-mockito.html and https://github.com/chiuki/android-test-demo. I had to extend the `Application` class and then custom runner replaces the actual application with mocked one. Then during test `setup`, you replace the component with a mocked one.

Comment: @Ranjan can you please share the code. I am trying to mock view model in activity with espresso test. But I am unable to provide the mocked view model.